# Getting wikipedia database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, web, localhost, wikipedia

I am making a website where I want to get content of Wikipedia so I need the database of Wikipedia in my localhost so how can I get it?

I cannot find any SQL file. Also, what is the difference between a database dump and a `.sql` database file?

Comment: lol. this post made my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia do not expose their base databases to the public, so you can't do that.

They also rather object to people 'stealing' large portions of their content - but I don't think that they actually do much about it. (Some content is licenced from original copyright holders. There would be objections about you copying stuff like that; I think it's mostly images though.)

Your only option is to scrape their website by downloading the HTML they generate. This will probably not be very useful and won't make you many friends.

Probably the best thing to do is create an account at Wikipedia, go to something the Community Portal (link top left bar) and then the Village Pump (where you ask questions) and ask them.

@HoschNok - indeed!

Cheers -